# MYSQL/PHP- echo inserted data out of database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, insert-into

I'm pretty new to this, so any help would be appreciated.
I have successfully inserted data into a database. But how can i echo the data inserted into the database out into a form field. I have tried the `value="<?php echo [variable here]; ?>"`. it does work all i get is

> **Notice**:  Undefined variable: c_fname in
>   **/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PhpProject2/customer/Cus_Account.php**
>   on line **129**

PHP

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Update'])) {
$c_fname = $_POST['fname'];
$c_lname = $_POST['lname'];
$c_email = $_POST['email'];
$c_phone = $_POST['phone'];



$insert_det = "INSERT INTO Cus_acc_details(CUS_Fname,CUS_Lname,Cus_Email,CUS_Phone) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $insert_det);
//new
// $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $insert_c);
//debugging
//$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $insert_c)  or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssi', $c_fname, $c_lname, $c_email, $c_phone);

/* execute query */
$r = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

if ($insert_det) {
    echo "<script> alert('registration sucessful')</script>";
 }
 } else {
echo "<b>Oops! Your passwords do not </b>";
}
?>
```

HTML

```
    <section class="container">
    <form id="myform " class="Form" method="post" action="Cus_Account.php?c_id=<?php echo $c_id ?>" accept-charset="utf-8">

        <!--                    <div id="first">-->
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="<?php echo $c_fname;   ?>" required> 
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"  required>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo    $_SESSION['Cus_Email']; ?>" required>
        <input type="number" id="phone" name="phone"  required>
        <input type="submit" name="Update" value="Update">
        <br>
    </form>
```

any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: `if ($insert_det)` should be `if ($r)`

Comment: @mondesilva really :s. because the insert is working perfectly. It is justing it to echo out the results is the issue

Comment: Yes, but I mean to validate correctly if the query execution(insert) works.

Comment: @mondesilva still doing the same thing. The same error message

Comment: Yes, The error will still be there, that is just additional correction. I will post an answer to fix your problem. But I want to ask if your HTML and PHP is on the same page?

Comment: @mondesilva thank you, that would be much appreciated as i think I'm misunderstanding what you are suggesting. And yes they are.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: Since your variable `$c_fname` is only set when `if (isset($_POST['Update']))` is `true`, you will get that error message on initial page load. You could prevent it by changing it to `value="<?php if(isset($c_fname)){ echo $c_fname; }  ?>"`. Another solution would be to define `$c_fname` before your `if (isset($_POST['Update']))`, ie. `$c_fname = "";`.

Comment: Is the php coded first before HTML? I mean is the PHP at the top before your HTML tags? Possible problem of `Notice` you have is you are trying to access $c_fname while it's not yet declared.

Comment: @mondesilva yes it is before the HTML

Comment: And where did you get `$c_id` in your `<?php echo $c_id ?>`?

Comment: @mondesilva it is another part of my code that i didn't include in this post as it was irrelevant to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is to keep the values in form once you submitted the data.

So If I'm right, Do this

```
<section class="container">
<form id="myform " class="Form" method="post" action="Cus_Account.php?c_id=<?php echo isset($c_id) ? $c_id : ''; ?>" accept-charset="utf-8">

    <!--                    <div id="first">-->
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['fname']) ? $_POST['fname'] : '';   ?>" required> 
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"  required>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['Cus_Email']) ? $_SESSION['Cus_Email'] : ''; ?>" required>
    <input type="number" id="phone" name="phone"  required>
    <input type="submit" name="Update" value="Update">
    <br>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Ive been pulling out my hair. it works